# Spring: how to ensure multiple parameters correlation

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Currently, I've this endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/group-attachments",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE
)
public ResponseEntity<String> group(
    @RequestPart("transactionId") String[] transactionId,
    @RequestPart("user") String[] user,
    @RequestPart("expiration") Date[] expiration
```

)

I'm running against an issue related with how to handle parameter correlation. I mean, according to this endpoint I'm able to set several `"transactionId"` or whichever parameter multiple times:

```
endpoint?transactionId=adf&transactionId=ewr&user=sdf&user=sfsdf&expiration=10/08/2019&expiration=21/09/2020
```

So, I'm going to receive:

```
transactionId = ["adf", "ewr"]
user = ["sdf", "sfsdf"]
expiration = [so on...]
```

When I process them it's important to take in mind that each n-position is related.

Is there anyway to ensure that?

Comment: Don't be easier to send a json payload instead?

Comment: Why not make one request bean? that would contain transationId, user and expiration, something like this `TransationInfo { transationId, user, expiration }` and send an array of these objects, this way related data would be in the same bean